# findOneAndUpdate increment instead of update in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function that suppose to add up or decrease credit. But my below code merely replace the credit value. Is there any shortcut in mongoose that I can do increment or decrement? else I will have to get the value then insert it back, which I think is not the way to do it.

```
function update_total_credit(total_amount, topup_value){
            User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {email: user_email}, 
                {$set:{credit:total_amount}}, 
                {new: true}, 
                function(err, response){
                if(err){
                    res.json(0);
                }else{
                    res.json(response.credit);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: It's replacing the credit value because that's what you are setting. `$set: {credit: total_amount}`. No where in your code did you use `topup_value`.

Comment: @Kai I know that, I'm not asking why it's replacing my value.

Comment: Did you try  `$inc` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the value dynamic and pass it in the query

```
function update_total_credit(total_amount, topup_value) {
//The flag value means your breakpoint where you decide which value should go in query, you can change on your requirement basis
  var flag = 1;    // increment by 1 every time
  if (!flag)
    flag = -1;     // decrement by 1 every time
  User.findOneAndUpdate({
      email: user_email
    }, {
      $inc: {
        credit: flag
      }
    },
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        res.json(0);
      } else {
        res.json(response.credit);
      }
    });
}
```

See the reference here for [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Comment: $inc can use negative prefix? I thought there is something like $dec no?

Comment: `$inc=1` mean increment by 1 and `$inc=-1` mean decrement by 1

Comment: `{new: true}` not required

Comment: Ohh my mistake I just updated his code with `$inc` removing it thanks, @MedetTleukabiluly

Answer (score 3):

Use `$inc` to increment particular field following way

**update:**

```
db.getCollection('noti').findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: ObjectId("5bc061f05a4c0511a9252e88") }, 
   { 
      $inc: { count: 1 } 
   }, {new: true })
```

**result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc061f05a4c0511a9252e88"),
    "count" : 8.0,
    "color" : "green",
    "icon" : "circle",
    "name" : "online visitor",
    "read" : false,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-10-12T08:57:20.853Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "views" : 1.0
}
```

Here, the count is incremented by 1 and before it was 7.

Comment: OP asked for increase or decrease. With this, you can decrease if the value is negative, but then you could also get a count of sub 0 causing all sorts of other problems