# Increment nested mongoose shcema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my model:

```
const telemetery = mongoose.Schema({
link: String,
originalLink: String,
creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
browerType: {
    Firefox: Number,
    Chrome: Number,
    Edge: Number,
    IE: Number,
    Safari: Number,
    Other: Number
}
```

I want to increment the value of the firefox by `1`

What I am doing now:

`const test = await Telemetery.findOneAndUpdate({link: req.params.link}, {browserType: {$inc : {Firefox : 1}}})`

But this still id not updating the document.
At the end I would also like to use a variable instead of `Firefox` so that the value is incremented dynamically with depending on the input.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946436/findoneandupdate-increment-instead-of-update-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increment the value in a nested object you can use the dot notation

```js
const test = await Telemetery.findOneAndUpdate(
  { link: req.params.link },
  { $inc: { 'browserType.Firefox': 1 } }
);
```

Inorder to dynamically set the field name you can do something like

```js
const browserName = 'Firefox';
const key = `browserType.${browserName}`;
const test = await Telemetery.findOneAndUpdate(
  { link: req.params.link },
  { $inc: { [key]: 1 } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I wanted to know that if I can use variable name as well  something like `browserType.[browserName]` while `[browserName]` is a variable